# apply with dynamic value

Tags: r, apply

How can I count all the values higher than the mean in a data frame in R? I mean, it's a different value for each column, because the mean of each column is not the same. Thank you!

Example:

```
a<-c(1,2,3)
b<-c(4,5,6)
c<-c(7,8,9)
df<-data.frame(a,b,c)
```

(How can I get the formula to count the values for each column, higher than the mean. Regarding the example above, the mean is 2,5 and 8, so assuming different values for each column.)

I would like to know the formulae to get how many observations are higher than the mean. But the mean is different for each of the 3 columns of the example above.

Comment: Hi Luis, can you provide a sample data frame and an example of what your correct output would look like? That would help make the problem reproducible and attract lots of people who would love to help you. Thanks :)

Comment: a<-c(1,2,3)
b<-c(4,5,6)
c<-c(7,8,9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider your matrix is `mat`, then this could be useful

```
Means <- colMeans(mat)
sapply(seq_len(ncol(mat)), function(i) sum(mat[,i]>Means[i]))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
data.df%>%summarize_all(function(x){sum(x>mean(x))})
```